# Designing a polarity-reversing electromagnet with energy recovery

Tags: energy-harvesting, electromagnet

I'm looking to design an electromagnet that changes its polarity by the trigger of a pulse signal, by considering the lowest energy drop, I am looking for a sub-system to reserve the energy of the electromagnet to re-use it.

- If there are known circuits performing these requirements, what are they called?
- If not, what are the suggested yet recommended composed circuits to make it up?

Thus the high-level elements I've are:

- Electromagnet, with the purpose to change its polarity.
- Sensor signal that's a pulse signal, consider a push button signal, but can be with a high frequency (Say 1kHz).
- Sub-system to reserve the electromagnet energy when flipped of polarity, which my question primarily aims to find.
- Control system to reverse the electromagnet's polarity, as an H-Bridge.
- The system voltage is 5-15VDC.

Note that utilizing an MCU is available to be utilized in the desired sub-system if needed, but anyway it's preferred if it can be substituted easily with electronics.

**Update - Drawing trials:**

1. Here's an idea where an H-bridge is utilized, the intended working:

- Starts with activating the first polarity of H-Bridge to complete a circuit (Switches SW1,SW4, and SW6).
- On a certain time that capacitor's voltage is about to equal the source voltage and blocking the current therefore, open the previous switches and let the electromagnet continue to self-feeding by closing the short-circuit switch (Switch SW5).
- On a trigger signal, close the inverse polarity switches of the H-bridge alongwith Switch SW6, and open switch SW5.
- Continue as the point 2.
- On a triggering signal, repeat the process.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjorJO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2. Here's another idea, where it goes in 4 major phases, presuming the circuit is kicked (C1 charged by the battery as the polarity appears and the inductor is passing current clockwise (Left to Right)).

- Close switch SW1, resulting in LC circuit, Inductor discharges as current (Left to Right) (CCW) --> Current stops with higher Vc1 --> Current flips in direction (CW) (Right to Left).
- When the capacitor voltage Vc1 decreases to 90% of its original voltage*, switch SW1 is opened and switch SW5 closes, resulting in L circuit with shorted ends.
  Meanwhile switch SW2 is closed to fully charge Capacitor C1.
- On the triggering signal, opens switches SW5 and SW4, and closes switch SW3 to inverse the polarity, as explained in point 1 but the other direction, resulting (Left to Right) current flow.
- When the capacitor voltage Vc2 decreases to 90% of its original voltage, switches SW3 opens and switch SW5 closes, resulting in L circuit with shorted ends.
  Meanwhile switch SW4 is closed to fully charge Capacitor C2.
- On the triggering signal, repeat the process.

/* this 10% (or any better number) due to the circuit losses, so feeding 10%Vc of energy each half-cycle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn3sUS.png)</sup>

Comment: To the admin, can you clarify what's missing? It's a broad question that doesn't discuss any detail, just the big picture. General guidance as (You'll need X and Y and Z circuits, you'll need to consider A and B).

Comment: @ocrdu Thanks for the edit, can you help me find out the missing points?

Comment: can you put in a block diagram of what you have designed already?

Comment: I've some attempts may be seen as naive, using switches (H-bridge in two attempts) and a capacitor (or two) to drive the periodic charging, discharging, reverse charging of the magnet. But what I think is that I'm trying to reinvent an already invented wheel, that's why I'm asking for guidance. If these circuits would help please ask for them. @VoltageSpike

Comment: There is a circuit tool to draw with if you edit the question

Comment: Great, I'll insert as soon as possible.